# Regex for finding and replacing hyphens with periods within brackets

Tags: regex, xcode

I know how to do a basic find-and-replace using `RegExp`, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do a find-and-replace between two parentheses. I have the following input:

```
"$(vc-alert)"
"$(vc-alert-error)"
"$(vc-alert-error_message)"
```

I want to produce the output:

```
"$(vc.alert)"
"$(vc.alert.error)"
"$(vc.alert.error_message)"
```

The number of hyphens to replace should be arbitrary. This is what I have so far:

```
/\"\$\(([\w_]+)(-([\w_]+))*\)\"/g
```

This works for finding the groups, but bunches all of the repeating parts into a single group. Therefore I cannot do a replace that works, e.g.

```
"\$($1.$2.$3...   (etc etc)
```

Is there a way to perform a find-and-replace within a loop like this using a regex? Can I use a look-ahead or a look-behind somehow?

Comment: `/\"\$\(([\w_]+)(-([\w_]+))*\)\"/g` is not Objective-C way of declaring a regular expression. Which language are you using in fact?

Comment: @stribizhev I thought I would show the regex in its 'pure' form, so I didn't limit myself to responses just from Obj-C programmers. I know how to translate for Obj-C.

Comment: Actually, also I shouldn't have tagged it Objective-C, because I'm actually doing the regex find-and-replace in the Xcode Find Navigator.

Comment: I suggest adding such "small" details to the question in the beginning to avoid such questions as mine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with a positive look-ahead that will require a closing round bracket after it:

```
(?=[^()]*\)[\w\s.,]*")-
```

Have a look at the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uT4eW5/4)

Comment: Actually, there is still a bit of a problem... This still matches hyphens within brackets that aren't also within quotes. Is there any way of adding an allowance for quotes too?

Comment: I thought the quotes are not part of the strings. `(?=[^()]*\)")-` should do. Answer is updated.

Comment: I understand the formula a bit better now. Just needed one final tweak: `(?=[^()]*\)[\w .,]*")-` so that it can match strings such as `"This is a $(vc.alert.error) message."` - something I didn't mention in the question. But great stuff, many thanks.